# Jquery datatables not showing data with javascript variable containing data

Tags: json, datatables

I am new to Jquery datatables. I have a javascript variable named varData containing an array.In the chrome console, I see the variable being printed as `Object {aaData: Array[110]}`. I am using the following code to display the jquery datatable.

```js
      $('#dataTable').dataTable( {
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
       "aaData": varData,
       "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "name" },
        { "mData": "age" },
        { "mData": "country" },
        { "mData": "state" },
        { "mData": "gender" },
        { "mData": "maritial_status" }
        ]
      });
```

The table is not getting populated with the data. Please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Hey are you making any server-side call ? aoData or aaData ? Possibly add more code and metion your approach . cheers

Comment: Let us see how the object / variable looks like (just a chunck, a few records)